# interpretation of a sentence -"だから別れ話しも　できなくって"

Tags: meaning, translation, interpretation

I am trying to understand the following short conversation. But I have some trouble understanding the last sentence.

> female 1: まだまだ　忙しそうだな…
>
> female 2 looking at phone sad: うん… だから別れ話も　できなくって…

My translation:

> Seems like [he] is still busy...
>
> Yeah... that's why I have not been able to connect [with him].

I feel like my translation of the second sentence is off. Because I don't really know how to interpret the "別れ話も". The literal translation I think is Parting conversation? I feel that, that does not sound right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

別れ話 means talking about separation. It appears that female 2 is planning to separate from her significant other, but due to him being busy, she hasn't been able to bring that up yet.

Answer (score 1):

別れ話 is “the discussion” that a couple has just before breaking up (別れる). So it seems “female 2” can’t get to broach the subject to her boyfriend(?) due to him being busy.